# Unable to filter multiple fields using filter

Tags: javascript, arrays

In Array I used name filter on the  (name,desc).  and I used flag. I tried using name I applied filter for name or desc and flag. but I am not getting two records. I tried to filter name for (name,desc) and flag. 
Below is my code

```js
var data = [
  {
    name: "hello",
    domain: "domain1",
    subdomain: "subdomain1",
    type: "yes"
  },
  {
    name: "hello",
    domain: "domain2",
    subdomain: "subdomain6",
    type: "no",
     desc: null,
      flag:null
  },
  {
    name: "helloo",
    domain: "domain2",
    subdomain: "subdomain6",
    type: "no",
    desc: "test",
    flag:"yes"
  },
  {
    name: "test1",
    domain: "domain2",
    subdomain: "subdomain6",
    type: "no",
    desc: "hello",
    flag:"yes"
  }
];

var name = "he";
var flag = "yes";
var res = data.filter((d)=>{return ( (name.length &&  d.name) ? d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) > -1: "" || (name.length &&  d.desc) ? d.desc.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) > -1: "") && (flag.length && d.flag)
    ? d.flag.includes(flag)
    : ""});

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

**name value I tried to filter (name , desc) and flag. but getting name and flag, unable to get desc having the text "he"** I need to get two records actually `{
    name: "helloo",
    domain: "domain2",
    subdomain: "subdomain6",
    type: "no",
    desc: "test",
    flag:"yes"
  },
  {
    name: "test1",
    domain: "domain2",
    subdomain: "subdomain6",
    type: "no",
    desc: "hello",
    flag:"yes"
  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sa name && description are always present, you are making useless checks.
Check out below if it is the result you are looking for:

```js
var data = [
  {
    name: "hello",
    domain: "domain1",
    subdomain: "subdomain1",
    type: "yes"
  },
  {
    name: "hello",
    domain: "domain2",
    subdomain: "subdomain6",
    type: "no",
     desc: null,
      flag:null
  },
  {
    name: "helloo",
    domain: "domain2",
    subdomain: "subdomain6",
    type: "no",
    desc: "test",
    flag:"yes"
  },
  {
    name: "test1",
    domain: "domain2",
    subdomain: "subdomain6",
    type: "no",
    desc: "hello",
    flag:"yes"
  }
];

var name = "he";
var flag = "yes";
var res = data.filter(d => d.name.indexOf('he') > -1 ||  d.flag === 'yes');

console.log(JSON.stringify(res.length));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should serve the purpose.
Club the relevant conditions:

```js
var data = [{
    name: "hello",
    domain: "domain1",
    subdomain: "subdomain1",
    type: "yes"
  },
  {
    name: "hello",
    domain: "domain2",
    subdomain: "subdomain6",
    type: "no",
    desc: null,
    flag: null
  },
  {
    name: "helloo",
    domain: "domain2",
    subdomain: "subdomain6",
    type: "no",
    desc: "test",
    flag: "yes"
  },
  {
    name: "test1",
    domain: "domain2",
    subdomain: "subdomain6",
    type: "no",
    desc: "hello",
    flag: "yes"
  }
];

var name = "he";
var flag = "yes";
var res = data.filter((d) => {
  return d.name && d.desc && d.flag && (d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) > -1 || d.desc.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) > -1 && d.flag.includes(flag))
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: if the name is optional we are not getting the flag having 3 records "yes" (var name = "";)  and flag is also optional